# redis.conf include: "Bad directive or wrong number of arguments"

Tags: configuration, redis

I've created this config for redis [/etc/redis/map.conf]:

```
include /etc/redis/ideal.conf
port 11235
pidfile /var/run/redis-map.pid
logfile /var/log/redis/map.log
dbfilename map.rdb
```

As you can see, it includes /etc/redis/ideal.conf; this file actually exists and we have read permissions.
Also there is another file, slightly different; consider [/etc/redis/storage.conf]:

```
include /etc/redis/ideal.conf

pidfile /var/run/redis-storage.pid
port 8000
bind 192.168.0.3
logfile /var/log/redis/storage.log
dbfilename dump_storage.rdb
```

My problem is: I can launch redis-server with **storage.conf** (and everything works fine), but **map.conf** leads to the following error:

```
Reading the configuration file, at line 1
>>> 'include /etc/redis/ideal.conf'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
failed
```

Version of redis is 2.2.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I would try to use od or hexdump to check whether some non printable characters are hidden in the include line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry guys.

I was using different instances of Redis.

Instance for **storage.conf** was launched by /usr/local/bin/redis-server, but **map.conf** launched by /usr/bin/redis-server; second one is broken.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was tearing my hair out over this.  I was getting the same error trying to include this module in redis.conf

`loadmodule /usr/src/RediSearch/redisearch.so`